# Material UI - Button inside stepper step

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I want to have a clickable element within a step from Material UI's stepper.
The element should be visible all the time and not only when a step is active. Setting all steps to active is not possible due to UX reasons.

Here's what I tried:

```
<Step key={x.id}>
    <StepButton completed={false} onClick={() => xxx()}>
        {title}
    </StepButton>
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <IconButton onClick={(e) => show()}>
            <InfoIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </div>
</Step>
```

But it seems like having a div inside a step is not allowed. Im getting errors in the div's row (e.g. Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute active.)

Then I tried to put the Icon in the StepButton tag:

```
<Step key={x.id}>
    <StepButton completed={false} onClick={() => xxx()}>
        {title}
        <IconButton onClick={(e) => show()}>
            <InfoIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </StepButton>
</Step>
```

But this is not possible either, because Buttons inside Buttons are not allowed.

Is there any other way to use a clickable element (like the IconButton) in a step?

Comment: @keikai Unfortunately not. There is no such prop like "title" for "Step", according to Material UI's docs. And I tried it and it's not working

Comment: `Steps` is not even a Material UI component. For `step` I checked this doc: https://material-ui.com/api/step/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a button inside a StepLabel:

```
import { Step, StepLabel, StepContent, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
```

placed like this:

```
<Step key={x.id}>
    <StepLabel
        onClick={() => handleStep(x.id)}
        completed={completed}
    >
        {title}
        <Button
            onClick={(e)=>{
            console.log("Button Pressed")}
            }
        >
            {"Button"}
        </Button>
    </StepLabel>
    <StepContent>
        {"Content hidden when not active"}
    </StepContent>
</Step>
```

If you want to prevent the button from opening the step, you can add a `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: This is working for the additional button. But it also creates a second button for the step

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is now, you want an additional button but not a second button? This should only create one button in each step. If you want to hide it, use a ternary condition to hide the button when active.